# Where can I watch One Punch Man season 2 legally?

Tags: one-punch-man, resources

I have checked Hulu, but it does not have episode 1 of *One Punch Man* season 2.

Where can I watch episode 1 to current legally?

Comment: when i google search i get [AnimeLab](https://www.animelab.com/shows/one-punch-man) and [Netflix](https://www.netflix.com/title/80117291), however they are just named One Punch Man so they might have Season 2 on there but also Anime Lab can be geoblocked to those outside of Australia while Netflix is giving me a Site Error which could be it's own geoblocking. Viz Media's site saying you can watch season 2 for free on viz.com but [their page on One Punch Man](https://www.viz.com/one-punch-man) doesn't list any streams even which could be because of geoblocking against Australia though not sure

Comment: Wikipedia lists Crunchyroll for Europe and Hulu for the US for the 2nd season of OPM, though...

Comment: You can try the sites mentioned by @Memor-X because I read that it's also on AnimeLab. Not sure if I'm allowed to mention this but you can use VPN to get around geoblocked sites.

Comment: @W.Are I know some other sites but I can't mention them here

Answer (score 1):

You are in the United States of America (Texas) according to your profile.  Here, One Punch Man is being shown exclusively on Hulu.

https://www.newsweek.com/one-punch-man-season-2-time-how-watch-1388310

Disregarding legal loopholes, that is the only place you can legally watch this show in the United States. I do not know why you were not able to find it.

Answer (score -1):

You can watch it legally at any of these websites: Crunchyroll; Yahoo View; Crackle; Viewster; Tubi TV.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Unfortunately, though, I think you might be mistaken. At very least, One Punch man is not available at all on Crunchyroll in the USA (where OP is).  I expect it is available there in other countrys.

Comment: @kaine It indeed is. I wasn't aware of the current Crunchyroll USA problem.